# Kittens - where did my concrete go?

Tags: kittens-game

In [Kittens Game](http://bloodrizer.ru/games/kittens/), my workshop seems to be missing the concrete button. I know I saw it there before. Did they remove it from the game? And if it's not removed, how can I get the button back?

Comment: I still got it (and just refreshed). Its between slab and plate. Can't you craft from the left side?

Comment: I'm here with the same problem, and unable to craft from the left side.

Comment: @Both. That's is weird. The last update is from over 2 weeks ago. Did you have this problem the whole time?

Comment: @BT I added a question to your question so it's more clear for people that want to answer it.

Comment: @Mathias711 Yes, I guess. It has been quite some time. Maybe they changed the requirements for making concrete.

Comment: @BT have you unlocked Mechanization??

Comment: I have not unlocked mechanization yet, I don't have anything that requires concrete yet, but I saw the concrete button right when I got my workshop, and sometime later it was gone. Maybe it'll appear once i have stuff I need concrete for?

Comment: @BT I've had the same thing, it's a bug read user2357112 answer. After I got Mechanization I could craft Concrete

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the v 0.9.9.5 [changelog](http://bloodrizer.ru/games/kittens/changelog.txt):

> Crafts no longer appear in the workshop tab before they get unlocked. (http://redd.it/2jg5jy)

You do not have Mechanization, so you have not unlocked Concrete. You had the button earlier due to a bug. To get the button back, research Mechanization.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question: it is **not** removed in game. I still got it and I got the latest version according to the changelog and due the fact I just saved + refreshed the game. I can craft it, both from the workshop as from the left side.

I don't know how to get it back. I assume you saved and refreshed, and have enough resources to craft it (2500 slab and 25 steel). You can make a bug report on [Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/kittensgame/) if it still does not appear.

Comment: I did try saving and refreshing, and I do have the resources to craft it